# C#-Hierarchical Iteration works differently

Tags: c#

When i make iteration over the following declaration  :

Car[] cars = new Car[2];

cars[0] = new Car { Speed = 100, Color = "green" };

cars[1] = new Car { Speed = 200, Color = "Orange" };

***using "foreach" i have no issue to iterate over the Car Array***

but as in the case of following :

**public class CarStore:Car**
    {

        Car[] m_collection = new Car[2];

```
    public CarStore()
    {
        m_collection[1] = new Car { Speed = 100, Color = "red" };
        m_collection[2] = new Car { Speed = 200, Color = "yellow" };
    }

}
```

Now i suppose to Use :

CarStore m_Store = new CarStore();

foreach (Car myCar in m_Store),iteration won't work until i use IEnumerator

---

My Question is :

1. How does CLR internally treat them? .First case it use System.Array,What happen 
         to second case of declaration ..?
2. Am i really unfit for coding in OOps world ?,for not  knowing such basic things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLR doesn't know anything about `foreach` really. It's all about the C# compiler:

- When the C# compiler sees an array, it will iterate over it using `Length` and the array indexer.
- When the C# compiler sees something implementing `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable` it will use `GetEnumerator` and then `MoveNext`/`Current` (and `Dispose` at the end).
- When the C# compiler sees something with a `GetEnumerator` method declared to return something which has appropriate `MoveNext()`/`Current` members, it will use that - but that was really to give type-safe collections pre-generics, and isn't used in new code.

Not knowing this doesn't mean you're not fit to program - it just means you should read a good book on C# before going too much further. The difference between ignorance and stupidity is that ignorance can be corrected :)

---

Basically you should implement `IEnumerable<Car>`:

```
public class CarStore : IEnumerable<Car> { 
    Car[] m_collection = new Car[2];

    public CarStore()
    {
        // Indexes adjusted - C# arrays are 0-based
        m_collection[0] = new Car { Speed = 100, Color = "red" };
        m_collection[1] = new Car { Speed = 200, Color = "yellow" };
    }

    public IEnumerator<Car> GetEnumerator() {
        return m_collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Just having the methods without implementing `IEnumerable<T>` would be enough to let the compiler use `foreach`, but with generics there's no benefit in *not* implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, and this way your class can be used in LINQ etc.

Btw, I've removed the idea that `CarStore : Car` because it seemed very unlikely to me that a `CarStore` is *actually* a `Car`... in your real case it may be more reasonable of course.

Comment: There's my own one, "C# in Depth"; also "C# 3.0 in a Nutshell" and "Accelerated C# 2008".

Comment: CLR via C# rocks as well, btw.

Comment: Hi ,I ordered your book ! Thanks for info

Comment: @Narresh see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/11/19/copenhagen-c-talk-videos-now-up.aspx for some of Jon's talks.

Comment: Or in general, http://csharpindepth.com/Talks.aspx - and hopefully next week there'll be links to another two I'm giving in Dublin :)

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` can't magically infer that you are building an enumerable collection. What it does is to see if it can call a `GetEnumerator` method that returns an `IEnumerator`. If it can't call such a method, the compiler will complain.

You'll have to provide a `GetEnumerator` implementation if you want to be able to use `foreach` on your own object:

```
public IEnumerable<Car> GetEnumerator() {
    foreach(Car c in m_collection) // btw, don't use `s_`, `m_`, `g_` prefixes
        yield return c;
}
```

Comment: While I totally agree with your advice to not use prefixes, that seems a little orthogonal to the question at hand.

Comment: akmad: that's why it's just a comment, prefixed by "btw" ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can iterate over the cars array because it is an Array, <del>which obviously implements IEnumerable</del> (See Jons comment below).  Your class CarStore is child of the Car type (which I assume is a child of object and does not implement the IEnumerable interface).  You cannot enumerate over the CarStore class because you did not implement the IEnumerable interface.

If you don't explicitly specify what thing you want to enumerate on the CarStore type how is the runtime supposed to figure it out?

Comment: This isn't correct for the C# foreach statement. You do not have to implement IEnumerable or IEnumerable<T>, you simply have to implement a method called GetEnumerator with a compatible signature.

Comment: In fact for arrays, the C# compiler doesn't use IEnumerable at all - it just iterates using the array indexer and Length.

Comment: @Jon... oops, thanks for the info!  @Greg... didn't know that either, I've always just implemented the interface.  However, I think that just creating a method with a compatible signature is not clear and is something I would definitely flag in a code review.  Nice to know it's there though!